# Pass Foreach variables through MySql Insert

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, api

I'm trying to go through data matches of a game thought the developer's API and store them in a database. How would I pass x.something through to my database. When I try something like this:

```
            using (var web = new WebClient())
            {
                web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                var jsonString = responseFromServer;
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var MatchesList = jss.Deserialize<List<Matches>>(jsonString);
                string connectString = "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
                MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
                MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT into data (level, name) values('" + x.Account_Level + "','" + x.Name + "')";
                string MatchesListStr = "";

                connect.Open();
                foreach (Matches x in MatchesList)
                {
                    MatchesListStr = MatchesListStr + ", " + x.Name + ", " + x.Account_Level + ", " + x.Reference_Name + "!";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(MatchesListStr);
            }
```

It says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'character,

Any help is appreciated, I'm new to C#. Thanks!

Edit -- Updated Code:

```
       using (var web = new WebClient())
       {
           web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
           var jsonString = responseFromServer;
           var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           var MatchesList = jss.Deserialize<List<Matches>>(jsonString);
           string connectString = "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
           MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
           MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();

           connect.Open();
           foreach (Matches x in MatchesList)
           {
               command.CommandText = "INSERT into data (level, mode) values(@level, @mode)";
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", x.Account_Level);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", x.Name);
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
           connect.Close();

       }

 public class Matches
        {
            public int Account_Level { get; set; }           
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Replying with same answer as prior.

Comment: I would look at using [prepared statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure characters are escaped properly. If you have odd characters in the x.Account_Level or x.Name variables, it will result in invalid SQL.

Comment: I have all of that written lower in the document. I didn't include it because I thought it was a given factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection%20SQL%20injection.). You should avoid this by [parameterising](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) your query.

I expect you're having an issue since the `level` column within the table takes as input an integer - when you are supplying a string.

I'd do something like this to sort your issue:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT into data (level, name) values (@level, @name)";
// Now let’s add the parameters themselves.
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", x.level);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", x.name);
```

Note: I'm also assuming that you are supplying a parameter named `x` (which is of type `Matches`) to the routine. This is why you should take more care when naming variables.

Comment: I made parameters for all the values I need. I still get the same error. Upon inserting a breakpoint, the parameters are displaying the correct values as expected, but its just having a problem with: command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Also, I have x.level set to be int lower in the code. I just didn't share that.

Comment: Ok - and you updated the CommandText as shown above as well?
Is it possible for you to execute the command directly on the server? You should be able to see the full command string when debugging or you will see if it in the Sql Server Profiler (when its running & logging.)

Comment: If the insert doesn't work when running it on the server directly, tune it till it does then update the CommandText as appropriate. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would run it on my server. It's a Visual Studio form and my server is on HostGator. Another thing, when I take out the command.ExecuteNonQuery(); line, It says:   An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Parameter '@level' has already been defined.

Comment: When I get rid of the parameters, it works just fine. I think I'm going to go with that until I can find a better solution. After all, I don't think that I can get injected when I'm accessing a company's program. Thanks though, I will return to this when I figure it out completely